# Placing graphic and algorithm on same page

Tags: graphics, floats, algorithms

If I have the following LaTeX code, is it possible to combine both graphic and algorithm so that they are fixed to a common page?

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\centering{\includegraphics[scale=1]{Figure.png}}
\caption{Figure.}
\label{fig:Figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \algsetup{indent=2em}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{1em}{} 
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \STATE $Line$ $of$ $code$
        \end{algorithmic}
        \caption{Algorithm.}
        \label{alg:Algorithm}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{algorithm}
```

To give something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would place the `algorithm` as a non-float - using the `[H]` float specifier - *inside* the `figure` float:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{This is a figure}
  \label{fig:Figure}

  \bigskip% Insert a gap between the figure/algorithm

  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
      \STATE Line of code
    \end{algorithmic}
    \caption{This is an algorithm}
    \label{alg:Algorithm}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5-20]

\end{document}
```

The `[H]` float specifier process the float as a immovable block, making it possible to embed it inside another float (`figure` in the above case). Since both objects are contained within the same float, they will *always* stay together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subfig` package to put both the figure and algorithm in a same float. You can add your labels and captions to each `subfloat`.

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[][a]{\includegraphics{<figure1>}}
    \subfloat[][b]{\begin{algorithmic}[1]\end{algorithmic}}
\end{figure}
```

Or using `subcaption`:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[⟨pos⟩]{⟨width⟩} ... \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[⟨pos⟩]{⟨width⟩} ... \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Or `minipage`, where use can still add subcaptions:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
     \includegraphics{<figure1>}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]\end{algorithmic}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

Or in many other ways that you can put your `algorithmic` environment as a sub-figure.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use `subfig` because it is incompatible with `subcaption` which I'm already using.

Comment: Then use the `subfigure` command from `subcaption` or use `minipage`. I included example above.